# Android CameraX GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, glsurfaceview, android-camerax

Please, can someone provide good example of using CameraX library with GLSurfaceView, can't find any information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for using CameraX with Custom surface / TextureView is non-existent. After the beta release of CameraX many API have changed so the existing examples online would work only with alpha versions. 
Link for using TextureView/GLSUrfaceView with alpha-xx versions:
https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/CameraXBasic

However these samples wont work for the latest beta-02 (as of today) versions.

Please refer the below sample that I used to create a TextureView with CameraX API.

Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies{
def camerax_version = "1.0.0-beta02"
.....
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha09"
...
}
```

Create a Activity for Preview: (Kotlin Example but similar in Java)

```
class Capture : AppCompatActivity(), CameraXConfig.Provider {
    // ur code


private lateinit var cameraProviderFuture : ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider>
    private lateinit var viewFinder: TextureView // Created in view file 
   // ur code


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_capture)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

// CameraX related Code 
        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)
        viewFinder = findViewById(R.id.view_finder)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
            val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
            bindPreview(cameraProvider)
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))

     // ur code here 
    }
}

private fun bindPreview(cameraProvider : ProcessCameraProvider) {
        var preview : Preview = Preview.Builder()
            .build()

        var cameraSelector : CameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
            .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
            .build()
var camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this as LifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview)
        val surfaceTexture = (view_finder as TextureView).surfaceTexture
        val surface = Surface(surfaceTexture)
        val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
        val previewSurfaceProvider = PreviewSurfaceProvider(surface, executor)
        preview.setSurfaceProvider(executor,previewSurfaceProvider)
        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview)
    }
```

Now Create a SurfaceProvider Class.

```
import android.view.Surface
import androidx.camera.core.Preview
import androidx.camera.core.SurfaceRequest
import androidx.core.util.Consumer
import java.util.concurrent.Executor
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

class PreviewSurfaceProvider (private val surface: Surface, private val executor: Executor): Preview.SurfaceProvider {

    override fun onSurfaceRequested(request: SurfaceRequest) {
        request.provideSurface(surface, executor, Consumer { result: SurfaceRequest.Result ->  {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }})
    }

}
```

Create the view xml activity_capture.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    // Can be replaced with GLSurfaceView
    <TextureView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/view_finder"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you help me with the GLSurfaceView?I tried to use GLSurfaceView but the request.provideSurface need a "surface", I tried a lot but don't know how to convert GLSurfaceView to Surface.

Answer (score 0):

[It's not a `GLSurfaceView` directly but a sample with OpenGL.](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/camera/integration-tests/coretestapp/src/main/java/androidx/camera/integration/core/OpenGLActivity.java)  You can use [OpenGLRenderer](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/camera/integration-tests/coretestapp/src/main/java/androidx/camera/integration/core/OpenGLRenderer.java) for effects.